# Match words but could possibly contain spaces within word

Tags: sql, regex, whitespace

Is there a way to match words in regexp (or SQL) with spaces so, for example,

`This`  would match to

- `T h i s`
- `T  hi s`
- `Th  is`

Comment: @Lion regexp or SQL (MySQL supposedly supports regexp)

Comment: what are you using as the word separator ?

Comment: @DavidChan also space :( The data comes from several thousand scanned pages, so there's nothing to be done about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\s*` after each letter, meanings that 0 or more white spaces. but you can use a simple solution using replace()...

```
WordThis.replace(' ','').equals("this")
```

Comment: Much better than adding `\s*` after every word, but it's a bit hard to see how this would work if there were more words than just "this", e.g., "Th is is a s e n ten c e ."

Answer (score 0):

You can try an expression like this `(t\s*h\s*i\s*s\s*)`.

You'll need to ensure your settings are case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is only way to add `\s*` manually between every characters in word.